# How to check LinkedIn web link using RegEx Patterns in Java?

Tags: java, regex, url-pattern

Can anyone help me please?
I am working on validation linked in url in java. I create a regular expression(which I am not familiar with) to validate the link however I am struggling with it.

The code is as follows:

```
public class TestRegEx {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        // List of valid URLs
        List<String> validValues = new ArrayList<>();
        validValues.add("https://www.linkedin.com/sometext");
        validValues
                .add("https://uk.linkedin.com/in/wiliam-ferraciolli-a9a29795");
        validValues.add("https://it.linkedin.com/hp/");
        validValues.add("https://cy.linkedin.com/hp/");
        validValues
                .add("https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=AAIAABQnNlYBIx8EtS5T1RTUbxHQt5Ww&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile");


        // List on invalid URLs
        List<String> invalidValues = new ArrayList<>();
        invalidValues.add("http://www.linkedin.com/sometext");
        invalidValues.add("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");
        invalidValues.add("google.com");
        invalidValues.add("http://uk.linkedin.com/in/someDodgeAddress");
        invalidValues.add("http://dodge.linkedin.com/in/someDodgeAddress");

        // Pattern
        String regex = "(https://)(.+)(www.)(.+)$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        for (String s : validValues) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            System.out.println(s + " // " + matcher);
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to create a regex to validate the following
  **Prefix:**                "https://"
  **Optional prefix:**       "uk." (it can be nothing or another country)
  **Middle:**                "linkedin.com/"
  **Suffix:**                "any characters with a max of 200 chars"

Regards

Comment: Why do you consider the invalid ones invalid? (Except `google.com`, I suppose). Also, why is `"https://www.linkedin.com/sometext"` both valid and invalid?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention. I am trying to validate a valid LinkedIn URL. Thank you

Comment: on the invalid "https://www.linkedin.com/sometext" it was meant to be without the HTTPS and with HTTP. Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would go with:

```
^https:\\/\\/[a-z]{2,3}\\.linkedin\\.com\\/.*$
```

<kbd>[LiveDemo](https://regex101.com/r/cI4gH9/1)</kbd>

---

```
^ assert position at start of a line
https: matches the characters https: literally (case insensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally
\/ matches the character / literally
[a-z]{2,3} match a single character present in the list below

    Quantifier: {2,3} Between 2 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)

\. matches the character . literally
linkedin matches the characters linkedin literally (case insensitive)
\. matches the character . literally
com matches the characters com literally (case insensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally
.* matches any character (except newline)

    Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

$ assert position at end of a line
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine using regex101, however when I add it to Eclipse a String it throws me an error "Invalid escape sequence". Is it something i am missing?

Comment: @WilFerraciolli fixed :) see the [diff](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33760587/revisions). It's because `\ ` have to be escaped to work well

Comment: I doubt you have to escape the `/` symbol. As a rule of thumb, place all the "special" characters into `[]`. Try `^https://[a-z]{2,3}[.]linkedin[.]com/.*$`

Comment: Nice one. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: @Thomas: Please refer to [character classes reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), especially *Metacharacters Inside Character Classes* section.

Answer (score 4):

updated regex

the link of profile changes in `/in`

`http(s)?:\/\/([\w]+\.)?linkedin\.com\/in\/[A-z0-9_-]+\/?`

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation. In this case please edit the answer to include why there was an update needed, what was updated, and how the regex accomplishes that.